# Fetching in javascript with absolute url and relative url

Tags: javascript, fetch

I have a script that I run on my local server and that fetches a php file (on the local server too). If I write the url to fetch as a relative path, I get the file without problems, but, if I add the 127.0.0.1/mypath/myFile, I get a 403 error.

```
function localServerCall() {
    var urlLocalServer = '127.0.0.1:8000/mypath/myfile.php';
    //var urlLocalServer = 'myfile.php';   //THIS WORKS!
    fetch(urlLocalServer).then(function(response) {
      console.log(response.json);
      return response.json();
  }).then(function(data) {
      console.log(data)
  }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log ('ERROR LOCALSERVER', err);
  })
}
```

I was wondering if there are some limitations on the use of absolute/relative urls with fetch or if this problem might be due to something else.

Comment: You forgot the protocol.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A URL that doesn't start with a scheme or with `//` is treated as a *path* (part of a relative URL).

From `http://example.com/foo/`, your URL resolves to `http://example.com/foo/127.0.0.1:8000/mypath/myfile.php`.

You almost certainly want:

```
var urlLocalServer = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/mypath/myfile.php';
```