# Similar function to fetch() in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I used to collect my data in the front-end by using fetch(), now I'm doing the same in my back-end (using node.js) but that threw an error

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): Error: only absolute urls are supported

That's because I'm fetching my Express route `` fetch(`/api/users/${userstate.username}`) ``

Is there a function in node that returns the same like fetch?

Comment: how about `http://localhost:port/api/...` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37725659/fetching-in-javascript-with-absolute-url-and-relative-url

Comment: Oh, you're right... I didn't think of solving it that way, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are inside your webserver you cannot use relative url's as you did. You will need to provide a hostname and optionally a port or protocol (http/https) if other than default, such as:

http://localhost:8080/api/users/user1

If you are actually inside the server that you want to make the request to it might be better to avoid the internal request altogether and call the underlying function directly. You might need to refactor some code here to avoid code duplication.